# React not rendering after asynchronous assignment

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite certain the problem is with the asynchronous behaviour. I think its because my react app conditionally renders when `userLinks.exists` is true but this only gets assigned once the firebase method is finished. Any suggestion on how to fix this? The page keeps rendering a blank screen with an error:

```
react-dom.development.js:13413 
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

app.js

```js
const User = async ({ match, location }) => {

  const userLinks = await firebase.getUserInfo(match.params.user)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { userLinks.exists ? <h1>Loaded and works!</h1> : <h1>Didn't work</h1> }
    </React.Fragment>
```

firebaseconfig.js

```js
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    this.db = firebase.firestore();
  }

  async getUserInfo (username) {
    let userInfo = { exists: false }
    await this.db.collection("users").doc(username).get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          userInfo.exists = true;
          userInfo = { ...userInfo, links: doc.data().links };
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    return userInfo;
  }

export default new Firebase();
```

Comment: The error says you're trying to render a Promise. What's the output of `userLinks`?

Comment: @AdamAzad Ah found out that output of userLinks is a <Promise />, but how do I grab the .then() value of this promise and update it to the react component in time? should I use useState like I did above? (I updated the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `async` / `await` doesn't make the code suddenly run synchronously. You still need to pay attention to returning promises and values, and bubbling them up.

In your code, I think that'd look like this:

```
  async getUserInfo (username) {
    return await this.db.collection("users").doc(username).get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return { exists: true, links: doc.data().links };
      } else {
        return { exists: false }
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but it still giving me the same error... Although, now if I .then() my userLinks, it gives me the right values, it just never updates the constant in time. Do you know why? I made an update to the post

Comment: You'll need to check whether the component is still mounted by the time the data becomes available. See https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+Can%27t+perform+a+React+state+update+on+an+unmounted+component Btw: it is not common to change your question as much as you did, as now my answer mismatches with the question - while in reality it solved your initial problem and moved you on to the next problem. More common is to either add the new code or (better) open a new question for the new problem *if* it persists after reading some of the search results.

Answer (score 0):

await wait for a promise to resolve or reject.
try
return Promise.resolve(userInfo);